# regex phone validator ^\+?(\d+)(-(\d+)|( \d+)+)?$

Tags: c#, regex

I need a phone validator with the following conditions:

- Optionally "+" at the start
- 0 or 1 hyphens
- At least 10 numbers

In Use the following regex: `^\+?(\d+)(-(\d+)|( \d+)+)?$`

It works but it counts "+" and "-" too.

I can write for ex `+123-45678`

10 chars but only 8 numbers.

There should always be at least 10 numbers

Comment: Could we please see your [mcve] that you have problems with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: The dash (`-`) can be anywhere in the string?

Comment: My comment above was asking for the specific c# code, probably Q just needs and [edit].

Comment: `(^\+?(?=\d+(\-\d+)?$))((\d{10,})|([\d\-]{11,}))$`

Comment: `^(?=(?:\D*\d){10})\+?(\d+)(-\d+|( \d+)+)?$` - here, `(?=(?:\D*\d){10})` will require the string to have at least 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this one part at a time:

- Optionally "+" at the start

You've achieved this already, with:

```
^\+?
```

- 0 or 1 hyphens

You can achieve this with a [lookahead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs):

```
^(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)
```

- At least 10 numbers

I presume that it should also contain ONLY numbers (and maybe a hyphen)? Again, using a lookahead:

```
^(?=(\d-?){10})
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
^\+?(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=(\d-?){10})
```

This regex would be a *lot* simpler if the validation rules were less vague. It really depends on what your intended use is.

Comment: What's your point? Your example was supposed to match, and it matches?

Comment: Ok see [v2](https://regex101.com/r/qK1uM0/2). it matches but it's not supposed to match

Comment: Ahh yeah, fine. OP didn't actually specify that the phone numbers could contain ONLY digits - although that seems sensible. I'll provide the "Improved" variation too.

Comment: and no letters :-|

Comment: Done. All I needed was to change `(\d.*)` to `(\d-?)`

Comment: Don't you think that is overly complex for a relatively easy requirement to just check a digit count? It can be done with just 1 lookahead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I suppose you could simplify it slightly to: `^\+?(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)[\d-]{10,}$`, but the improvement isn't massive :/

Comment: Yes, but `(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)` prevents such a string from matching :) https://regex101.com/r/qK1uM0/4

Comment: ^\+?(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=(\d-?){10}) well done! But it works med hyphen at the end

Comment: @Ivaapr At a certain point, when the pattern matching gets too crazy, it's probably worth considering *not* doing this in one big regex ;) However, you could achieve this by simply changing the pattern to: `^\+?(?=[^-]*-?[^-]+$)(?=(\d-?){10})` (I just replaced a `*` with `+`).